# MacBook Air - No internal speaker sound after boot (icon not greyed out + no red light)

Tags: macos, audio, macbook, speakers

I don't know when I've started having this, but with my MacBook Air 2015 13", the volume icon only shows "Headphones" as an output device option.

The icon is *not* greyed out, **nor** is there any red light coming from the headphone jack. The startup chime works fine as well.

- Resetting NVRAM - *didn't work*
- Resetting SCM - *didn't work*
- Re-plugging in the headphones (multiple times) - *didn't work*
- Twirling the headphone plug (multiple times) - *didn't work*
- Blowing in the headphone jack (multiple times) - *didn't work*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself, by having the MacBook sleep overnight.